# Python scipy agglomerative clustering not working correctly

Tags: scipy, data-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a bunch of points in 2D (rows of x) and want to cluster them so that each cluster has diameter < d (I don't know the number or size of the clusters beforehand). If I use [complete linkage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage), then the diameter condition should be achieved. Why does the following code produce *completely incorrect* results? (points in an individual cluster are far apart)

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage,fcluster
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib.pyplot    as plot1
import pandas,numpy
n=100; x=pandas.DataFrame(data=numpy.random.rand(n,2))
plot1.figure(figsize=(10,7)); plot1.scatter(x.iloc[:,0],x.iloc[:,1],s=3); plot1.show() 
ll=fcluster(linkage(pdist(x),'complete'),t=0.2,criterion='distance'); l=numpy.unique(ll)
print('number of clusters:',len(l))
xx= [x.iloc[numpy.where(ll==i)[0]] for i in l] #xx=clusters of x
for x in xx[:5]: 
    plot1.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    plot1.scatter(x.iloc[:,0],x.iloc[:,1],s=3)
    plot1.show(); #plot each cluster in a separate figure
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, my initial code *was* working correctly, it just seemed incorrect because the axes were shrunken, so `plot1.axis([0,1,0,1])` was all that was missing.

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage,fcluster
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib.pyplot    as plot1
import pandas,numpy
n=100; x=pandas.DataFrame(data=numpy.random.rand(n,2))
plot1.figure(figsize=(10,7)); plot1.scatter(x.iloc[:,0],x.iloc[:,1],s=3); plot1.show() 
ll=fcluster(linkage(pdist(x),'complete'),t=0.2,criterion='distance'); l=numpy.unique(ll)
print('number of clusters:',len(l))
xx= [x.iloc[numpy.where(ll==i)[0]] for i in l] #xx=clusters of x
for x in xx[:5]: 
    plot1.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    plot1.scatter(x.iloc[:,0],x.iloc[:,1],s=3)
    plot1.axis([0,1,0,1])
    plot1.show(); #plot each cluster in a separate figure
```